# Adding dependencies to microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

I have built few microservices that consume a number of external services. Few of these external services are consumed by more than 1 microservice that I have built. I have built the connectors to these microservices as a library project and have included it as a dependency in all my microservice projects. However I read that all logic for microservices should be self contained and duplication of logic is ok. If that's the case , is it recommended for me to define these connectors within each every microservice instead of having a shared library?

Comment: "All logic for microservices should be self contained and duplication of logic is ok" [citation needed]

Comment: @dnault - how about https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/01/microservices-sharing-code. I agree with your sentiment, however, it was fairly easy to find proponents of the above statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...all logic for microservices should be self-contained and
>   duplication of logic is ok

I think this is the core of the issue you are struggling with. Is this statement actually true?

A quick google search later:
http://www.simplicityitself.io/our%20team/2015/01/12/sharing-code-between-microservices.html

This article talks about this exact question, which we can now frame as *What is the appropriate level of re-use in microservice architecture?*

The author provides a list of reasons why developers feel the need to share code, ordered from lowest to highest in terms of coupling and loss of isolation:

> - Leverage existing technical functionality
> - Sharing data schemas, using a class, for example, as an enforcement of a shared schema.
> - Sharing data sources, use of the same database by multiple services.

Though this list covers most of the reasons, I would add another important reason to share code, which is to do with a common framework for rapid standing up of microservices, commonly called the [Microservice Chassis](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservice-chassis.html) pattern.

The author goes onto say:

> It is of utmost importance to pin down your motivation for wanting to
>   share code, as unfortunately there is no right answer to this
>   question. Like everything else, it’s contextual.

So, all that said, should you centralize your connectors or not?

Well, where do these dependencies fit in on our list? And what degree of coupling can you endure before you're no longer doing microservices but building a monolith instead?

These are not easy questions to answer, but hopefully this will help guide you to the correct conclusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Tom. Yes , I need think over it. For now I believe sharing the data scheme of connectors using a library seems to be the best approach. But I guess I need to think about it when I hit any issues.